# People picker very slow with active directory

Tags: active-directory, people-picker

Using a standard people picker on a task form - searching the AD (active directory) is very slow.

Example:

- John Smith (smith@domain.com)

When I enter **smith** in the people picker and hit CTRL+K or the little checkmark, the user is resolved right away as *"John Smith"*.

Now when I use the addressbook feature and search for "smith", it takes about a minute for it to find "John Smith".

The AD contains about 2000 users so size is not the issue. How can I analyze this issue and speed up the search?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

It might be that you are blocking an AD port in your firewall
see this http://www.wildwires.com/blog/10-10-27/Slow_People_Picker.aspx

Answer (score -4):

Microsoft AD is simply very slow to query.  There is no way to speed it up.  Eventually people will wonder why the performance is so ridiculously bad, and something will replace AD but you're stuck with it for the next long while.  I suggest a background job that copies the query into a database or flat file, and have your program read that.

Comment: I don't think this solution would be time/cost-effective for SharePoint integration.

Comment: You don't seem to know what you are talking about.